# MvvmCross vNext: ObservableColletion is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: xamarin.android, portable-class-library, mvvmcross

I have got my PCL model to build now, which took a bit of time making plug-ins, however now in my Android UI project I get two errors when building it.

First error is:

```
The type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1<T0>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.
You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e,
Retargetable=Yes'.  C:\ENM\Main\src\prod\Mobile\Stakeholder\UI.Android.vNext\Views\LocationsMapView.cs  40  32  UI.Android.vNext
```

The second error is:

```
foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 
'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1<BK.EMS.Stakeholder.Model.ViewModels.LocationViewModel>' 
because 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1<BK.EMS.Stakeholder.Model.ViewModels.LocationViewModel>' 
does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'
C:\ENM\Main\src\prod\Mobile\Stakeholder\UI.Android.vNext\Views\LocationsMapView.cs  40  32  UI.Android.vNext
```

I have referenced the `System.Windows` assembly from the `System.Windows.Droid` project, which is supposed to forward `ObservableCollection<>`.

The lines where the error occurs:

```
private void AddLocationOverlays()
{
    if (_itemizedOverlay.Size() > 0) _itemizedOverlay.ClearOverlayItems();
    RunOnUiThread(() =>
    {
        foreach (var location in ViewModel.Locations)
        {
            _itemizedOverlay.AddOverlayItem(location);
        }
        _mapView.Invalidate();
    });
}
```

The `Locations` property in my ViewModel looks like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<LocationViewModel> Locations
{
    get { return _locations; } 
    set
    {
        _locations = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => Locations);
    }
}
```

Nothing too complicated and works fine in the non-PCL models...

So how do I get around and fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We now have a solution to this problem - see fix from Daniel Plaisted in [Portable Class Library strong assembly reference problems in MonoTouch/MonoDroid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028321/portable-class-library-strong-assembly-reference-problems-in-monotouch-monodroid)

This fix is checked in at https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/commit/f6a88048467838e5ac5ca687744dc0b2d1958aa8

Answer (score 1):

**Update** : See other answer. It appears we now have a solution to this problem!

---

I believe this is linked to this problem - [Portable Class Library strong assembly reference problems in MonoTouch/MonoDroid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028321/portable-class-library-strong-assembly-reference-problems-in-monotouch-monodroid)

Which is linked to: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/41

This is raised with Xamarin as a bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=8035 and

I'm afraid I don't understand the recommended Strong Signing solutions right now.

Please upvote the bug report to alert the Microsoft PCL and Xamarin teams about this. The MS and Xamarin teams are talking to each other on this (albeit through me!), and I am hopeful we will find a way for either Microsoft or Xamarin to ship some signed DLLs.

---

In the meantime, some possible workarounds are:

1. Use IEnumerable access instead of ObservableCollection - the collection can still be an ObservableCollection instance, just don't reference it as an ObservableCollection in the UI code.
2. Try putting your iterating code in a class library rather than in an application project - bizarre as it feels, the compiler seems perfectly happy building the same code when its in a library rather than in an application
3. Try building in MonoDevelop with the Mono compiler - this doesn't seem to have the same strong name reference checks.

---

Looking at your sample code I would just try:

```
private ObservableCollection<LocationViewModel> _locations;
public IEnumerable<LocationViewModel> Locations
{
    get { return _locations; } 
    set
    {
        if (value != null && !(value is ObservableCollection<LocationViewModel>)
        {
            throw new Exception("You must Set an ObservableCollection");
        }
        _locations = (ObservableCollection<LocationViewModel>)value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => Locations);
    }
}
```

then `AddLocationOverlays` could stay the same.

The only problem with this would be if you then wanted to bind to `INotifyCollectionChanged` on this collection - but I think you can find a way around this too if needed - e.g. you could somehow expose another INotifyCollectionChanged hook, or you could try using a hack involving an intermediary class library.

---

I accept that for now these are workarounds not solutions :/

Comment: As to the code sample changing `ObservableCollection` to `IEnumerable` will not work in the setter as you cannot cast `IEnumerable` to `ObservableCollection`. You would have to create a new `ObservableCollection` from the `IEnumerable` like so: `new ObservableCollection(ienum.ToList());`

Comment: Going to wait a bit until all the teething troubles are resolved. I will probably have a play with vNext on the side though and report in my findings.

Comment: Thanks - cast problem fixed (assuming you are never setting this from the UI side - that problem remains!). No worries on what you choose. Thanks for the reports.