# Portable Class Library assembly reference problems in MonoDroid and MonoTouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, portable-class-library

I have problem in my project where I have PCL for .Net 4.5, Windows Phone 8, WinRT, MonoTouch and MonoDroid, when I try to build MonoDroid or MonoTouch project that have reference to that PCL errors are following:

> *Error 1 The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
>
> Error 2 The type 'System.Enum' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

I have done [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028321/portable-class-library-strong-assembly-reference-problems-in-monotouch-monodroid) command (sn -Vr *,b03f5f7f11d50a3a), but it didn't help. I am using the following profile:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile78
```

Answer (score 3):

If you set the compability to from .NET 4.5 to .NET 4.0.3 it will work.

Comment: I'm using Profile131. (.NET >= 4.0.3, Silverlight >= 4, Windows Phone >= 7.5, Windows Store Apps, XBox) and it works well with Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS)

Answer (score 1):

When I've encountered similar errors in profile 104, then I've built fake System assemblies like System.Windows.dll and System.Net.dll which type forward the classes in question. I've delay signed these fake assemblies - fortunately MonoDroid and MonoTouch don't seem to check these delay signings too carefully.

The examples of these are at: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/tree/v3/PortableSupport

I would guess you could do the same thing with 2 System.Runtime assemblies linked against MonoDroid and MonoTouch and type-forwarding System.Object and System.Enum.

Hopefully Xamarin's PCL support will ship soon - and will include official version for these shim assemblies.

Comment: I tried to use System.Runtime shim from Daniel's AsyncFacade project but it didn't help. I also tried changing versions from 1.0.0.0 to 4.0.0.0.

Comment: Tweet from @DavKean sent too - "Have you tried the ones under C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades?"

Comment: I will try now. Already rolled back my changes, so need a few minutes.

Comment: Tried now. Worked for MonoTouch, still fails for MonoDroid.