# Portable Class Library System.Object error

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, .net-4.5, portable-class-library, xamarin-studio

I am using Portable Class Libraries (PCL) in Xamarin Studio on OS X.  I have two PCL libraries that are targeting .NET 4.5, Windows Phone 8, Windows Store Apps, Xamarin.iOS, and Xamarin.Android.  I reference these two libraries in my iOS, Android, and Unit tests projects.  In 3 areas I am getting the following error:

> The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

The code is straightforward:

```cs
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
```

The error occurs once in each of the projects that reference the PCLs.  None of them are the same class.  I am new to PCLs.  I've tried removing the Windows Phone 8 (as I added it last minute) and yet the problem does not go away.  Any help would be appeciated!

Thanks!

**Update:**

So this occurs with the first field declared in the class (where the class is from the PCL project).

```
int a = 0;
MyPCLClass _myPCLClass = new MyPCLClass();  //This is where the error appears
```

Another odd aspect is that there are over 50 classes using these classes, and the error is only appearing in three classes.

Comment: this is profile 78, right ?

Comment: Yes it is profile 78.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just ran into this exact same problem, and have the same setup as you do. A tip mentioned in a comment (by Stuart, which in turn mentioned a tweet by @DavKean) to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153155/portable-class-library-assembly-reference-problems-in-monodroid-and-monotouch) question solved it for me.

You have to:

- access a Windows machine (I used a Windows 8)
- grab `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Runtime.dll`
- copy it to your Mac
- add a reference to this `dll` from each of your iOS and Droid projects

Comment: That did fix the error.  However, that is definitely not how it should be fixed.  Which brings up a question.  Is the System.Runtime.dll that Mono (Xamarin) use there own implementation?  I filed a bug for this, here is the link if anyone is curious.  Thanks for the help.  https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=13400

Comment: I'm having identical issues - but using Monotouch for VS. When adding the System.Runtime.dll VS no longer throws an error - but when building an error is still throw in the console. 

Have you tried this on Windows at all?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS are you using? You need to be using of the Xamarin.Android 4.7.x alphas for PCL support, or the forthcoming 4.8 release. (Ditto for Xamarin.iOS: you need a pending future release for PCL support, or use the alpha channel.)

Comment: I just upgraded on the beta channel yesterday (Jul 20, 2013) to Xamarin.Android 4.8 and Xamarin.iOS 6.3.8.  I was under the impression that the PCLs were supported in this release.  Do I need to switch to the Alpha channel?

Comment: AFAIK, PCL support is currently available in Alpha channel only

Comment: @jonp I'm still running into this issue on the alpha channel