# How to correctly implement type forwarding?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, portable-class-library

I am about to write a shim assembly for Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions to be able to build Mono projects (I described the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16389315/microsoft-threading-tasks-extensions-in-xamarin-mono-projects)), but there are a few things I am not sure.

1) Assembly contains the following methods (some with multiple overloads):

- FromCancellation,
- HandleEapCompletion
- ReadAsync
- WriteAsync
- FlushAsync
- CopyToAsync
- CopyToAsyncInternal
- ReadBlockAsync
- ReadLineAsync
- ReadToEndAsync
- WriteLineAsync
- GetResponseAsync
- GetRequestStreamAsync

How can I find out which types I should forward and which methods to implement? And those that should be forwarded, where should I redirect them? In this case I suspect I will have to provide implementation because they don't exist in Mono assemblies, but how do I know for sure?

2) Do I need to implement or type-forward everything, or only stuff that is used in my code? In a latter case, if I skip some of the required types or methods, how will I know? I noticed that I am not getting a compiler error for missing methods - it only complains about missing assembly with no hint about what methods it is looking for. Will I get any hint from a compiler if I leave unforwarded types or not implemeneted methods?

**UPDATE**. There are two types defined there: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskServices and AsyncExtensions. None of them is known to Android/Touch projects. I can only forward types that are referenced by the assembly, and these two are not. Does this mean I have to implement them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't really be type-forwarding methods - instead you should be type-forwarding types.

My advice - based on what I did for System.Windows and System.Net - is to start by type-forwarding all types in the reference assemblies.

After you do this - when you build - you'll probably discover some that won't type-forward. For those you can either:

- simply miss them out - in which case some code will later fail at runtime with some variant of `Missing` exception.
- implement stub versions - with liberal helpings of `NotImplementedException`
- implement replacement versions (although I would shy away from doing this - would probably be better to talk with the Mono guys and try to patch the Mono implementations)

I believe the new Mono3 implementations of the `Async` code is very complete - so I don't think you should hit too many problems.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant forwarding types and implementing methods, but wrote something else :-) So I guess it is Mono.Android and monotouch assemblies I should be forwarding missing types. Will give it a try. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Hm, please read my update. There are only two types there but none of them is present in referenced assemblies. Since I can only forward known (referenced) types, how am I supposed to do this? Define fake types?

Comment: Are the methods (extension methods?) implemented in some other type in mono? If they are you could write shims to forward them (with one extra call on the stack) - I hope this would mean you could avoid writing the methods from scratch. One other resource to check out is mr skeet - I think he wrote lots of the TPL stack 'for fun'

Comment: "Are the methods (extension methods?) implemented in some other type in mono?" - No as I know, but I need to search. Basically the whole Mono stack is new to me, so I am doing a lot of discoveries these days, and the challenge of forwarding non-existing types adds even more fun.